# Existence of Moment Generating Function

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

Give a example of discrete random variable for which $M(t)=E\left(e^{tx}
\right)$ does not exist .    I have tried with geometric(p) distribution when $(1 - p)e^t ≥ 1$ , the mgf does not converge. Is it correct approach ?

Comment: Yes, that is fine. Another example: $X=n$ with probability $\frac c {n^{2}}$ where $c=\frac 6 {\pi^{2}}$.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this pmf. Do you know any particular name of this distribution

Comment: Also asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/618460/existence-of-moment-generating-function

Comment: @geetha290krm - I am not sure the original suggestion is fine: there is convergence in a neighbourhood of $t=0$ so in that sense a geometric distribution does have an MGF, while your example does not.

Comment: @Henry You are right.  I was careless.